# Google Authenticator not giving correct verification code

Tags: server, gnupg, google, ntp, two-factor-authentication

I'm setting up a google authenticator for a linux image that i'm creating. Every time it gives me a verification code it's different to what my phone gives me.

My question is because this is time based. How do I check what time tool that google authenticator is using? It's clearly not using the same datetime as my system because that would be correct. (I send the date command on my linux image and verify the time against my phone)